# How to filter for an empty list in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a field in my model which is a StringListProperty. The default value is an empty list: []. Is there a way to filter for all entities with an empty list under this field?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to create another property like `isListEmpty` with boolean value so you can filter by it. If you use `ndb`, you could use [ComputedProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed) for this.

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    my_list = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    is_list_empty = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: True if not self.my_list else False)
```

**UPDATE**: Actually, I think you could check if that list is empty on each put, and if it is -- populate it with some constant value like `['__EMPTY__']` so you can query it later without introducing another property.